# Python Jira module is not found, but it's installed

Tags: python, php, jira

I have two files - one PHP file and one Python file. The python file imports the Jira module, searches for issues, and obtains information from Jira. This file does function correctly and it will find Jira issues and return all needed fields successfully.

The PHP file (for this example, let's call it `py_exec.php`) is part of a website and executes the Python file through `shell_exec`; something to the effect of:

```
$jira_issues = shell_exec(python3 py_search.py issue=blah);
print_r($jira_issues);
```

- When I run the Python script directly, the script works correctly.
- When I execute the PHP script directly, which in turn executes the Python script, the script works correctly.
- But when I run the PHP script from the website, the script returns nothing.

After troubleshooting a bit, I tried to run the command as the apache user and I am given the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jira'
```

Obviously the module is installed, but it seems that it's not accessible to Apache.

How do I make this module accessible to Apache?

Many thanks, in advance, for any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` to the `apache` user and run `pip install jira`. Check that it worked by doing `python` and then `import jira`.

Sometimes `pip` ends up aliased to something other than `python`. So if you have issues, try `python -m pip` instead.

Comment: I had to do a little finessing to get to login as apache (I was just kicking off the process using the service before), but once I got in as apache and installed Jira, things worked perfectly. Thank you!